# Is there an easier way to write conditional statements with NumericVector in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to write up some code using Rcpp, and I'm trying to get the hang of how conditional statements work between logical vectors as they arise from comparisons using NumericVector, and C++'s native bool type.

The method that I've settled on is as follows (minimal reproducible example, my example was more complicated):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector compare(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
   if (is_true(all(b <= a))) {
     return a;
   }
   return b;
}
```

However the is_true and all seem redundant if (for instance as in my more complicated case that I am not showing you), a and b are guaranteed to be of length 1.

Now did I just find a ridiculously convoluted technique, or is this an unfortunate case of 'this is the best we've got (and the reasons for this approach are better than the reasons against, despite edge cases like this)'?

Comment: If it is *guaranteed* that both vectors have length 1, then why don't you just compare first element: `return b[0] <= a[0] ? a : b;`?

Comment: Why do you use `NumericVector` for `a` and `b` when their length is guaranteed to be 1?

Comment: Re: Ralf Stubner, I tried to implement the Bisection method using Rcpp for practice, and so there's an input function (something like function(x) {exp(x)-2}) which since it is coming from R, outputs a numeric vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `is_true()` and `is_false()` are required for use with `all()` Rcpp sugar function because:

> The actual return type of all(X) is an instance of the SingleLogicalResult template class, but the functions is_true and is_false may be used to convert the return value to bool.

c.f. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/unofficial-rcpp-api-documentation/#all

---

The only way around this is to implement the loop yourself (hinted at by @Aconcagua):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector compare_loop(Rcpp::NumericVector a, Rcpp::NumericVector b) {

  if(a.size() != b.size()) Rcpp::stop("Lengths of a and b must be the same.");

  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    // take opposite of comparison or switch it to b[i] > a[i]
    if ( !(b[i] <= a[i]) ) {
      return b;
    }
  }

  return a;
}
```

Test:

```
a = c(-1, 2, 3, 5)
b = c(-3, -2, 4, 3)

all.equal(compare_loop(a,b), compare(a,b))
# [1] TRUE
```